# SQL two rows into one based on three columns

Tags: sql, merge

Currently I have this:
current situattion
[image]

As you can see the only difference between Id 1 and 2 is that the Sort is diff (Be or Ov). I currently have the four measurescolumns 
BAR_fr
BAR_to
M2_fr
M2_to

I want to create 8 measurecolumns the difference will be the Be and Ov data
BAR_fr_Be
BAR_to_Be
M2_fr_Be
M2_to_Be

BAR_fr_Ov
BAR_to_Ov
M2_fr_Ov
M2_to_Ov

new situation
[image]

I am trying to merge two rows into one into sql based on three columns
FunctionId, RegioId, Year, I suppose. I have tried with Pivot but I didnt get the result I want yet. Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images, or - even worse - links to images.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: regiod is different, I would expect those to be different rows. You're going to need to show us what the expected result is. You should also include differing FunctionId and Years.

Comment: This can be achieved by using a self join

Comment: It is in SSMS/SQL. The Id;s do change, just there is two rows for every items/combination of Id's, which should be one. I will have a look at self join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have your tables setup, you could populate the new one with this:

```
INSERT INTO
YourNewTable
SELECT
T1.functionid,
T1.regionid,
T1.[year],
T1.BAR_fr,
T1.BAR_to,
T1.M2_fr,
T1.M2_to,
T2.BAR_fr,
T2.BAR_to,
T2.M2_fr,
T2.M2_to
FROM
YourOldTable T1
INNER JOIN
YourOldTable T2
ON
T2.regionid = T1.regionid
AND
T2.functionid = T1.functionid
AND
T2.[year] = T1.[year]
WHERE
T1.Sort = 'Be'
AND
T2.sort = 'Ov'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `functionid` INT,
  `regionid` INT,
  `sort`varchar(200),
  `year` INT,
  `BAR_fr` FLOAT,
  `BAR_to` FLOAT,
  `M2_fr` INT,
  `M2_to` INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `table` (id, functionid, regionid, sort, year, BAR_fr, BAR_to, M2_fr, M2_to) VALUES
  ('1', '1','1', 'Be',2010,8.0,9.5,1315,2710),
  ('2', '1','1', 'Ov',2010,9.0,10.75,485,1315),
  ('3', '1','2', 'Be',2010,7.25,9.0,1115,3165),
  ('4', '1','2', 'Ov',2010,8.9,10.5,270,1115);


SELECT t1.functionid, t1.regionid, t1.year, t1.BAR_fr BAR_fr_Be, t1.BAR_to BAR_to_Be ,t1.M2_fr, t1.M2_to M2_to_Be, t2.BAR_fr BAR_fr_Ov, t2.BAR_to BAR_to_Ov,t2.M2_fr M2_fr_Ov, t2.M2_to M2_to_Ov
FROM `table` t1
  JOIN `table` t2 ON t1.functionid = t2.functionid AND t1.regionid = t2.regionid
WHERE t1.sort = 'Be' AND t2.sort = 'Ov';
```